Are there carbon fiber wing spar pins?
Thinking about parts and weight saving, I've never seen a pin made of carbon fiber, is there such a thing for the aviation industry?

Not that I know of, and at first glance it seems like a bad idea.
Carbon fiber is great in tensile strength (and compression, if properly supported), but spar pins are mostly loaded in shear. In composites it is the matrix, not the fibers, which transmit shear. Compared to steel, epoxy resins are really poor in shear transmission.

Even Graphlite pultruded rod which is 300ksi+ tension and just under that in compression, and probably the best material for a spar cap there is, wouldn't do well as a bolt.

@JohnK. Gotcha.

@Peter Kampf, I kind of get what you mean but can you expand a little bit, specifically  about the shear matriz and  fibers. I think this would be good for general knowledge.

@Gabe, compare it to reinforced concrete being used in some shearing load application, like a giant reinforced concrete shear pin holding up a bridge. The rebar doesn't help because the load is across the bars, and the concrete itself is only strong in direct distributed compression, with relatively little shear strength. Just replace the concrete part with epoxy resin and the rebar with  glass or graphite.

@JohnK ok now I get a better visual idea and understand better Peter's answer.

Also my understanding is that carbon fibre itself is weak in shear, which is why it cam be cut with scissors. Fancy winding patterns can only go so far to make it strong to e.g. bursting pressure in the case of air bottles, the epoxy is basically there to restrain the fibres in relation to each other rather than to provide strength itself.
